# How to find the longest header file(.h) in the /usr directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

How to find the largest as in total size (by length) header file (.h) in the /usr directory ? 
To search in subdirectories too.
I did this as follows:

```
find . - name *.h | xargs awk | sort -n | less .
```

But this only outputs all files with the extension .h and their dimensions

Comment: Length as in total size, or number of lines?

Comment: Length as in total size.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU tools:

```
find /usr -type f -name "*.h" -printf "%s %p\0" | sort -zrnk1,1 | head -zn1 | tr '\0' '\n'
```

This allows filenames with newlines, `find` outputs a NUL terminated string and the following commands use NUL as delimiter instead of a newline. At the end of the pipeline, `tr` converts the delimiter back to a newline.

If you only want the filename, add `cut` to remove the first space separated field:

```
find /usr -type f -name "*.h" -printf "%s %p\0" | sort -zrnk1,1 | head -zn1 | 
  tr '\0' '\n' | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
 find /usr -name "*.h" -printf "%s\t%p\n" | awk '$1 > maxsize { maxsize = $1; maxline = $0 } END { print maxline }'
```

(assuming none of the files have newlines in their names, of course)

or if you have [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) available:

```
find /usr -name "*.h" -printf "%s\t%p\n" | datamash -f max 1 | cut -f1,2
```

With GNU find, the `-printf` command lets you print lots of information about a file, including its size in bytes (`%s`) and its name (`%p`).  Finding the max from that is easy.

Comment: These print the size and the filename; if you just want the name, it's a trivial change. Let me know and I'll make it.